# How to convert this PHP Regex to Javascript Regex?

Tags: javascript, regex

Honestly, I am horrible with regular expressions and I needed a ton of help making this PHP regex. Although, I have decided that I need to convert a ton of my code to Javascript.

Here is my PHP regex:

```
if(preg_match('/^(([^,]+,){4}[^,]+\n){3}$/', $all_questions))
```

Could someone give me a hand on converting it to a Javascript regex?

Greatly appreciated, thanks!

Comment: **Regex** is common in all language.  Not specific.

Comment: @user1671639 No, it’s not. Furthermore, there are quite some [significant differences between the various implementations](http://www.regular-expressions.info/refflavors.html).

Comment: @user1671639 Not really. It depends on Regex parser language/technology uses. There're different implementations and they differ slightly but unless you use some advanced features, it isn't noticeable.

Comment: Although there are differences between regular expression flavors, the one you are using can be used as is in Javascript without the need for any modification.

Comment: @Gumbo, Leri Oh Thank you so much for the pointers.  I thought that regex expression tend to be same in all languages.

Comment: @downvoter - Mind explaining why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In JS, you can do it simple do a [**.test()**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/test) with Regex(no need to change the expression).

```
var yourRegEx=/^(([^,]+,){4}[^,]+\n){3}$/;
if(yourRegEx.test($all_questions) {  // replace $all_questions with your
                                     // js variable
}
```

Comment: @fizzix you want to test it with a PHP variable? or you have a equivalent js variable for that?

Comment: It is still returning an error what I cant the variable to `fullString` which is my JS variable name.

Comment: @fizzix `yourRegEx.test('<?= $all_questions; ?>')`

Comment: @Leri - I won't be using that PHP variable anymore. So it would be `if(yourRegEx.test(fullString)){alert("Working")}`

Comment: @fizzix And what stops you?

Comment: @Leri - Managed to get it working in the end. Although, the regex still isn't working. My original question was to try and get this PHP regex converted into a Javascript regex. Not to test if my PHP regex works in Javascript since I already knew that it wouldn't.